# Prestashop 1.5 How to add products to cart from module

Tags: php, prestashop

I just started learning prestashop module development and I'm curious about few things.

I'd like to create a module similar to t-shirt designer where users can select any t-shirt that they like from module and customize it. Would it be possible to pass products to cart that do not exist in prestashop? I mean I need that customized products would be only visible in my t-shirt module and I don't want to add them manually via backend as products. I just want to pass customized product to cart. Are there any prestashop built-in functions to do so?

Answer (score 0):

**You can add the product into cart using the following below code:**

```
        $this->id_product = (int) Tools::getValue('id_product', null);
        $this->id_product_attribute = (int) Tools::getValue('id_product_attribute', Tools::getValue('ipa'));
        $this->customization_id = (int) Tools::getValue('id_customization');
        $this->qty = abs(Tools::getValue('qty', 1));
        $this->id_address_delivery = (int) Tools::getValue('id_address_delivery');

        if (!$this->context->cart->id) {
                if (Context::getContext()->cookie->id_guest) {
                    $guest = new Guest(Context::getContext()->cookie->id_guest);
                    $this->context->cart->mobile_theme = $guest->mobile_theme;
                }
                $this->context->cart->add();  //create cart if not available
                if ($this->context->cart->id) {
                    $this->context->cookie->id_cart = (int) $this->context->cart->id;
                }
            }

        $this->context->cart->updateQty(   //to add product into cart
              $this->qty,
              $this->id_product,
              $this->id_product_attribute,
              $this->customization_id,
              Tools::getValue('op', 'up'),
              $this->id_address_delivery
         );
```